# Color of NA-values after using mask

Tags: r, plot, mask, r-raster

Is there any way to change the color of NA-values in R?
I have masked out some values in a raster stack and was wondering, if I can change the color of the masked values from white to e.g. yellow?
I am using plotRGB for plotting my masked raster files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not familiar with `plotRGB`, but it belongs also to the `raster` package with the same function `colNA`, which is described in `?colNA` as `"color for the background (NA values)"`.

```
library(raster)

#simulating missing values
tg<-matrix(1:15,nrow=3)
tg[2,3]<-NA
tg[1,5]<-NA

#rasterize
tg_raster<-raster(tg)

#normal plot
plot(tg_raster)

#replace NAs with blue color
plot(tg_raster,colNA="blue")
```

Answer (score 0):

As nadizan pointed out, you can use the `colNA` argument. See the documentation for `plotRGB` (`?plotRGB`). Example:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
b[b > 250] <- NA
plotRGB(b)
plotRGB(b, colNA="red")
```